# MAAS is creating swap file by default

Tags: maas, swap

I'm using MAAS 2.3.5 to provision my bare metal host with Ubuntu 18.04 - bionic.
when i log in to my newly provisioned host i'm noticing that a swap file exist.

none of my preeseeds file (curtin_userdata files) contains anything related to swap configuration.
When checking the installation output of my node in MAAS web ui 
i see that indeed the swap file was set during the curtin installation (node installation logs snippet bellow).

**My question is:** where does this swap file settings is configured?
Is it MAAS defaults?
Is it curtin defaults?

**Installation log output:**

```
Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Setting up grub-gfxpayload-lists (0.7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic (5.0.0-32.34~18.04.2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...

Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 8 GiB (8589930496 bytes)

no label, UUID=7b5caee9-40e4-45b8-a712-8b7cbb121df3
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
```